# Reading all shapefiles in folder using GeoPandas and then clipping them all iteratively using GeoPandas

Tags: shapefile, geopandas, clip

I have a folder full of shapefiles, I would like to read them into geopandas and then clip them all to one bounding box iteratively.

However, I'm stuck on the first part which is reading each shapefile into geopandas as its own geodataframe.

Could anyone advise?

```
import glob
import geopandas as gpd
for filepath in glob.iglob('E:/folder/*.shp'):
    gpd.read_file(filepath)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can store each GeoDataFrame in a list or a generator to avoid any memory issue.

```
import glob
import geopandas as gpd

files = glob.iglob('E:/folder/*.shp')
gdfs = (gpd.read_file(file) for file in files) # generator

# A list is an option for small files
# gdfs = [gpd.read_file(file) for file in files]

for gdf in gdfs:
    # clip stuffs
```

Or

```
import glob
import geopandas as gpd

for filepath in glob.iglob('E:/folder/*.shp'):
    gdf = gpd.read_file(filepath)

    # clip stuff with gdf

    # save the clip result
```